# How a DAML application is adapted from Fabric network?

Tags: daml

I was reading this documentation https://github.com/digital-asset/daml-on-fabric but I am confused. I am trying to understand the workflow and the architecture for the daml on fabric network. The network has 2 orgs and each org has 1 peer.On step 4 are allocating 5 daml parties. Quickstart example has 3 signatories(issuer,owner,buyer). To sum up, what is the match between daml parties and fabric orgs? I think that could be allocated even more daml parties without to change fabric network. They interact from one node? What is the purpose to add other nodes on step 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parties don't have a cryptographic identity in DAML Ledgers, only nodes do. As part of the shared ledger state, every DAML-enabled infrastructure maintains a mapping from Party to Node. This relationship is usually described as a Node "hosting" a Party. The Node hosting a Party is able to submit transactions using that Party's authority and is guaranteed to receive any transactions visible to that Party.

In the tutorial you are referring to, all parties are allocated on a single Node, which then hosts them. This does indeed not make that much sense in practice. It would be more sensible to set up a network with three orgs and allocate the three parties on the peer nodes in the three orgs, respectively. Given the way the example is set up, that should be straightforward.